# Docker containers are running but can't access them

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm learning docker and have started with [Official get started Tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/).

My problem is on step 3.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file (it's the same as in the tutorial)

```
version: "3"
services:
web:
# replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
image: username/repo:tag
deploy:
  replicas: 5
  resources:
    limits:
      cpus: "0.1"
      memory: 50M
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
ports:
  - "4000:80"
 networks:
  - webnet
```

I followed the instructions in the [link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/).
The only thing that was different, when I ran `docker swarm init` and got  this response *Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on different interfaces (10.0.2.15 on eth0 and 192.168.99.100 on eth1) - specify one with --advertise-addr* I ran `docker swarm init --advertise-addr=192.168.99.100` as that's the IP address the command `docker-machine ip default` returns

**The problem**
All the 5 replicas of the containers are up and running but I can't access the app on 192.168.99.100:4000. What's wrong?

Here is what I get now
[Debugging commands results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWkwC.png)

**Notes:**

- Using Docker Toolbox for Windows (Windows 10 Home)
- I tried the command `docker swarm init --advertise-addr=192.168.99.100 listen-addr=192.168.99.100` too

Comment: what does `docker ps` show ?

Comment: @YOLO I attached an image with the commands

Comment: pick a id from `docker ps` output and do: `docker exec -it your_id bash`

Comment: Do you actually need a multi-host Docker Swarm installation?  The "part 2" tutorial is required reading, but beyond that I feel like most developers don't actually need Swarm.

Comment: @YOLO I did, inside the container I can see the files I expected to see, Is there anything specific you want me to check.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just want to go through all the 5 steps,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out something was wrong with docker-machine itself. After recreating it, everything worked all right.

Hope this will help anyone

Answer (score 1):

You can use the long-format to declare ports in your docker-compose.yml file like in the following file `test-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  web:
    image: jwilder/whoami:latest   
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - target: 8000
        published: 4000
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
    driver: overlay
```

With ingress mode you should be able to reach the service on any node of your Swarm cluster on port 80.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#using-the-routing-mesh for more information regarding Swarm routing mesh and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1 for long port syntax.

I tested this on Windows 10, just ran `docker stack deploy -c test-compose.yml test` and could see `I'm <hostname>` displayed when visiting `localhost:4000`

You should be abled to reproduce this. 
Are you sure that your python server are listening on port 80 and are not binded to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: This docker-compose file doesn't work for me, the same problem like the one in the official tutorial @gcharbon

Answer (score 0):

For my issue I had to stop then restart the docker damon via the command line:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

then:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Everything came back online.